# aws_sdk version 3 syntax not working after updation of runtime to node18.x

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless, versionupgrade

I was previously using node14.x and aws-sdk version 2 on my aws lambda setup. Currently I have updated my node runtime to node18.x in my serverless.yml file. After that I have tested with all the features I have in my code base , everything was working perfectly fine. And then when moved to aws-sdk 3 syntax like moving `const { S3 } = require('aws-sdk')` to `const { S3 } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3)` after I am facing issues that the module not found.
Node version- 18.16.0
serverless version - 2.59.0

I have also tried with adding the aws-sdk's required packages in package.json itself.

Comment: Could you please share the full error? In the example you provided there's a missing `'`, so I'd love to make sure what is the exact error you're seeing.

Comment: The `'` was not in my code. That was a typo in the question.
After updating to node18.x through my severless.yml file i changed the importing syntaxes as i have mentioned above. After that When i tried to run m tests to deploy i faced issue that @aws-sdk/client-s3 Module not found so i added them to the package.json, which resolved the module not found error and deployed successfully. But, after that when i tried invoking the feature it doesnt work and showing `Error message Data Not Found`.